# VueJS redirect issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication

I am learning to use VueJS by developing a user login system.

I would like to ensure that a logged in user can no longer go to the login or register page by being redirected to the dashboard page.

I am using `store.js` to store user data.

In my `router.js` I tried to do this:

```js
    path: '/signin',
    component: SigninPage,
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
      console.log(store.state.userId)

      if (store.state.userId) {
        next('/dashboard')
      } else {
        next()
      }
    }
  }
```

The `store.state.userId` key returns the `userId` to me if a user is logged in. In my views this key returns me the userId when I'm logged in, but in my router it always returns me `null`.

However, I did import `store.js`.

```js
import store from './store'
```

When in my `router.js` I do a `store.state` console.log I get the information well.

[Console log object store state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxOUl.png)

On the other hand when I try to retrieve my `userId` key, it appears as null.

Can you clarify where I am blocking?
No matter how hard I try to understand, I can't.

Comment: It's hard to know what the problem is but try **persist** packages for vuex to be able to save your vuex data in Local Storage or Cookies and then read `userId` from one of them in your router

Comment: How does the vuex package persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beforeRouteEnter is a in-component guard, which should be in the component itself, not in the registered route.
It should not even be called, I have no idea how it outputs something in your app.

Try beforeEnter(to, from, next) if you want to specify the logic in the router itself.

For deeper insight, here the official documentation: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards

EDIT:I know discovered the issue myself, it has something to do with that, for some reason, the state does not "load" fast enough in the router js. I would suggest to put the logic in the created function of the app.vue